# Rspec 3 and Fabricator - controller spec, unable to create new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, fabrication-gem

I am trying to solve this without success. I am using RSpec with Faricator and can't get tests pass. The problem appears in create action. Update (with similar syntax) works just fine. From website form everything works correctly so I believe it is rather problem with specs.
controller spec:

```
describe 'POST #create' do 
  before { set_current_admin admin }
  context 'admin users' do 
    context 'a successful create' do 
      before do 
        post :create, director: Fabricate.attributes_for(:director)
      end

      it 'saves new director object' do  
        #require 'pry'; binding.pry
        expect(Director.count).to eq(1)
      end

      it 'redirects to directors path' do 
        expect(response).to redirect_to directors_path
      end

      it 'sets a successful flash message' do 
        expect(flash[:success]).to eq('Reżyser został zapisany.')
      end
    end
  end  
end
```

set_current_admin admin method logs user as admin. I've checked using pry that logging is correct and logged user is an admin. Director controller:

```
class DirectorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_director, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :show]
  before_action :admin_user, except: [:index, :show]

  def create
    @director = Director.new(directors_params)
    if @director.save
        flash[:success] = 'Reżyser został zapisany.'
        redirect_to directors_path
    else
        flash[:danger] = 'Coś poszło nie tak, spróbuj ponownie.'
        render :new
    end
  end
```

Do you know what might be solution for that?

Comment: When the POST is executed, is the path being followed the one that assigns to `flash[:danger]`?  If so, what is the output of `assigns(:director).errors` in the commented binding.pry location?

Comment: got:
  => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000002bcfca8
   @base=
    #<Director:0x00000002bd90f0
     id: nil,
     name: "Horacy Banaś",
     created_at: nil,
     updated_at: nil,
     photo_url: "https://robohash.org/sitdoloret.png?size=300x300&set=set1",
     birth: Sun, 04 Apr 1965,
     bio: nil>,
   @messages={:bio=>["Can't be blank."]}>

It seems that Faker::Hipster.paragraphs doesn't work. I have changed it to Faker::Lorem.paragraph and worked nicely! Thank you Ben for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so specs are correct. I have used wrong Faker element - `Faker::Hipster.paragraphs` instead of `Faker::Hipster.paragraph`. First one generated an array and second a string.